# PHP CURL POST upload file with subarray variable

Tags: php, file, curl, post

do you have any idea, how to post file with subarray form fields

Simple example:
I need to have in form  multiple var[] variables. So I build post array:

```
$curlfile = curl_file_create($filename);
$postdata = array('file'=> $curlfile,
                  'var' => array('value1', 'value2')
            );

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```

Then I will make simple post request, but it is not working.
When I inspect the result with https://httpbin.org/post or print_r($_POST) variable on my site, it will show only

```
Array
(
    [var] => Array
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found solution,

```
$postdata = array('file'=> $curlfile,
                  'var[0]'=>'value1',
                  'var[1]'=>'value2'
        );
```